# Execute CMD command through JSP file

Tags: java, cmd

I'm trying to execute a CMD command through a JSP file but it gives out error : Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

```
String runtimecmd = "C:\\Users\\me>schtasks.exe /query /tn "\\dummy\\file" /v /fo list | find "Last Run Time:" > C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\lastRunTime.txt";
System.out.println(runtimecmd);
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(runtimecmd);
```

I am not sure how to decipher the error.

Comment: The quotation mark `"` terminates the string. If you want the quotation mark in your string then escape it `yourString = "someText \"\\dummy\\file\" some more text";`

Comment: There's a real problem with `C:\\Users\\me>schtasks.exe` - that's not a valid path.   (Specifically this bit: `>`)   `schtasks` is usually on the Windows path, so just try "`schtasks.exe /query ...`

Comment: `C:\Users\me>` is the __prompt__ in the Windows command prompt window which is not part of the command to execute. The prompt informs the user which directory is the current directory - `C:\Users\me` in this case - and `>` informs the user that it is now possible to enter the command line. The real command to execute is `%SystemRoot%\System32\schtasks.exe /Query /TN "\dummy\file" /V /FO LIST | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "Last Run Time:" >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\lastRunTime.txt"` which must be encoded as required for a string in a JSP file. `\dummy\file` is a strange task name.

Comment: This command line needs to be executed using `cmd.exe` started with option `/c`. But in my opinion it would be better that in the Java application code is used using `ProcessBuilder` class to run just `schtasks.exe` with the appropriate arguments with its fully qualified file name determined before by getting the value of environment variable `SystemRoot` concatenated with `"\\System32\\schtask.exe"` and capture the output to standard output by `ProcessBuilder` and search with Java code in the captured output for the data of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `exec` (in class `java.lang.Runtime`) does not serve as the equivalent of a [command prompt](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/a-beginners-guide-to-the-windows-command-line/) window. The method arguments are the name of an executable that you wish to run – which in your case is [schtasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks) – together with any options required by that command. Again, in your case the command options are:

```
/query /tn "\\dummy\\file" /v /fo list
```

However, as stated in the *javadoc* for class [java.lang.Process](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html)

> As of 1.5, `ProcessBuilder.start()` is the preferred way to create a `Process`.

Therefore you should rather use class [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Also, since you are launching the command from Java code, you should use Java code to handle the output of the `schtasks` command.

The below code is a stand-alone, console application that demonstrates executing `schtasks`, locating the `Last Run Time` line from the command output and saving that line in a file.

Note that if file `schtasks.exe` is not in any of the folders of the `System` property `java.library.path` then you need to supply the full path to `schtasks.exe`.
(More notes after the code.)

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class SchTasks {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("schtasks.exe",
                                               "/QUERY",
                                               "/FO",
                                               "LIST",
                                               "/V",
                                               "/TN",
                                               "\\dummy\\file");
        String result = null;
        try {
            Process p = pb.start(); // throws java.io.IOException
            BufferedReader out = p.inputReader();
            String output = out.readLine();
            while (output != null) {
                if (output.startsWith("Last Run Time:")) {
                    result = output;
                }
                output = out.readLine();
            }
            int status = p.waitFor(); // throws java.lang.InterruptedException
            if (status == 0  &&  result != null) {
                try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\lastRunTime.txt")) {
                    pw.println(result);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException | IOException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

- Method `inputReader` was added to class `Process` in JDK 17 so if you are using an earlier version, you can use method [getInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()) instead.

Here are the contents of file `lastRunTime.txt` after I ran the above code.

```
Last Run Time:                        30/11/1999 00:00:00
```

I assume that you actually need to do something with the actual last run time (of task `\\dummy\\file`) so rather than save it to a file, you can convert it to a timestamp in Java code. The below code replaces the part of the above code that saves the result to a file.

```java
if (status == 0  &&  result != null) {
    String[] parts = result.split(":\\s{2,}", 2);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                                              Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDateTime lastRunTime = LocalDateTime.parse(parts[1], formatter);
    System.out.println("Last Run Time: " + lastRunTime);
}
```

Refer to the following:

- *javadoc* for method [split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)) (in class `java.lang.String`)
- [Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) lesson in Oracle's Java tutorials.
- [Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) trail in Oracle's Java tutorials.